# Projection postulate and the state of a system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

*Quantum Mechanics*, McIntyre states the **projection postulate** as:

> After a measurement of $A$ that yields the result $a_n$, the quantum system is in a new state that is the normalized projection of the original system ket onto the ket (or kets) corresponding to the result of the measurement:
>
> $$\left|\psi^\prime\right> = \frac{P_n\left|\psi\right>}{\sqrt{\left<\psi\right|P_n\left|\psi\right>}}.$$

Then we do a Stern Gerlach type experiment as shown in figure below (The X, Z are analyzers that measure the  x, z spin of incoming stream of atoms. The up arrow is up spin.
At the right end is the final counter)

[image: Blockquote]

The author then says that

> the state of atoms input to the final Z analyzer is $$\begin{aligned}\left|\psi_{2}\right\rangle &=\frac{\left(P_{+x}+P_{-x}\right)\left|\psi_{1}\right\rangle}{\sqrt{\left\langle\psi_{1}\left|\left(P_{+x}+e_{-x}\right)\right| \psi_{1}\right\rangle}} \\ &=\frac{\left(P_{+x}+P_{-x}\right)|+\rangle}{\sqrt{\left\langle+\left|\left(P_{+x}+P_{-x}\right)\right|+\right\rangle}} . \end{aligned}$$ because  both states are used, the relevant projection operator is the sum of the two projection operators foreach port, $P_{+x}+P_{-x}$, where $P_{+x}=|+\rangle_{x x}\langle+|$ and $P_{-x}=|-\rangle_{x x}(-\mid$.

I'm not able to understand why should the state input to the final Z analyzer be$$\begin{aligned}\left|\psi_{2}\right\rangle &=\frac{\left(P_{+x}+P_{-x}\right)|+\rangle}{\sqrt{\left\langle+\left|\left(P_{+x}+P_{-x}\right)\right|+\right\rangle}} . \end{aligned}$$

How does this follow from the projection postulate?

Comment: You write *"because both states are used, the relevant projection operator is the sum of the two projection operators foreach port"*, and then you say you don't understand how the result comes about. But you already wrote down an explanation for that right before that, so I don't really understand what you're asking here - can you be more explicit *what* you don't understand?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put the commas. I'll edit. Thank you